# Missing delimiter (. inserted). error in array environment

Tags: arrays

It is a ``missing delimiter (. inserted)."-type error. I spent a great amount of time but still can't spot the missing part. Can anyone help to fix it?

```
\begin{align*}
    \begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
         &   & & &          & \\
         & A & & & \big\ast & \\
         &   & & &          & \\\hline
         &   & & &          & \\
         & 0 & & & B        & \\ 
         &   & & &          & 
    \end{array}  
\end{align*}
```

Comment: `\big` works only on delimiters, so parantheses, brackets, braces and a couple of other things. It won't work on `\ast`.

Comment: @campa Yes, it completely solves the question! Thank you so much!